# How to spin up/down a single container within docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file that contains 4 containers: redis, mongo, elastic and rabbitmq.

Instead of spinning down all services on my end, I want to spin down a specific service called rabbitmq at a given point in time. Let's say, after some time I want to spin down a different service, say redis, and spin up rabbitmq - can I achieve this? Can I automate this process, instead of running commands in command-line every single time?

Comment: Could you use [docker-compose stop SERVICE](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/stop/)? Can you clarify what you mean by "automate this process instead of running commands..."?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used shell scripting to receive user arguments and processed them accordingly.

Comment: This answer is not useful to future readers.